# PostgreSQL copy row minus a few columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

How can I duplicate a row, excluding a couple columns, without listing out every column I want to copy?  My concern is doing it as an `include` vs. an `exclude` is that if I add a new column or remove a column from the table, I have to remember to update this stored procedure that does the clone to list the new columns.

Comment: Why not copy the whole row and then set the excluded columns to NULL?

Comment: Because I'd get a primary key violation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly list columns or use `*`. No shortcut for `* except short_list`. You can try hacking this with dynamic sql, preparing query from existing columns from eg `information_schema.columns`:

```
t=# select column_name,ordinal_position from information_schema.columns where table_name ='s160' order by ordinal_position;
 column_name | ordinal_position
-------------+------------------
 id          |                1
 a           |                2
 b           |                3
 c           |                4
 d           |                5
(5 rows)
```

So saving previous column list ang comparing it against current would give you new columns and you can adapt changes in `execute format(...`, but honestly - it leads to more problems then specifying explicit list of columns every time.